# Обертка для бибилиотек (function(){})()

Tags: javascript

Часто видел когда код JavaScript оборачивается в такую конструкцию:

```
(function(){
// ... код ...
})();
```

Для чего это нужно?
Пример одной из таких библиотек можно посмотреть [здесь](http://ejohn.org/files/htmlparser.js).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это называется "замыкание" и используется для создания собственных пространств имен. Подробнее можно почитать на [javascript Гарден](http://shamansir.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.scopes). Зачастую это свойство применяют для пробега по массиву:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i){
    a[i].onclick = function(){alert(i);return false;}
}
```

В этом случае каждая ссылка будет выдавать окошко с количеством ссылок (i = a.length).

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i){
    (function(n){a[i].onclick = function(){alert(n);return false;}})(i);
}
```

А в этом случае создается замыкание, и значение n не берется извне. То есть, ссылки будут выдавать при клике свой порядковый номер.

Comment: спасибо за ссылку на сайт

Comment: Вы не совсем правы, это будет замыканием, только если оставить ссылку на внутреннюю переменную где-нибудь во внешнем контексте.

В данном случае это скорее всего простая уловка, да-бы не захламлять глобальный NS.

Answer (score 7):

Вызывает функцию сразу после объявления.
т.н. "немедленный вызов объявленной функции", если взять кальку с английского.
Эквивалентно:

```
function abc(){
//something;
}
abc();
```

ну, а нужно чтобы можно было этим куском пользоваться независимо, в т.ч. управление областью видимости, чтобы при вставке в чужой код как можно меньше всего пострадало.

Comment: Это понятно! Но, если код не оборачивать, он тоже выполнится...

Comment: См дополнение. =) Полезно, например, при попытке создать синглтон.

Comment: Я так понял, это своеобразное экранирование локальных переменных?..

Comment: В том числе. Скажем так, именно для этого его чаще всего и используют, например, вставляя на страницу сторонние счетчики