# Самовызывающиеся функции JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
(function(a){
    alert(a);
}(1));


(function (a) {
    alert(a);
})(1);
```

В чем отличие этих функций?

Или вот из примера Стефанова:

```
var result = (function () {
 return 2 + 2;
}());

(function () {
 alert(‘watch out!’);
})();
```

Comment: Найдите дубликат, кто-нибудь!

Comment: [33173](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/33173), [391114](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/391114), [189242](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/189242)...

Comment: Что вы набросились? Человек дело спрашивает.

Comment: Doofy, посмотри внимательно на мой вопрос и на те дубликаты , которые ты дал, я не спрашивал что значит эта конструкция, я спросил в чем отличие разных вариантов записи

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Разницы, в общем-то, нет.
[Дуглас Крокфорд](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4,_%D0%94%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81) посчитал что запись:

```
(function () {
    //body
}());
```

Является правильной, а нотацию:

```
(function () {
    //body
})();
```

Неправильной и пренебрежительно называет её "собачьи яйца" (dog balls).

---

Поэтому используйте ту, что больше нравится (я, к примеру, согласен с Дугласом, хотя второй вариант ничуть не раздражает).
Например в `Perl` вообще слоганом предписано что **всё** должно иметь несколько путей нотации.
Чем `JS` хуже? :)

Comment: http://largescalejs.ru/module-pattern/ - кстати вот тут автор тоже в примере с jquery реализует вариант Дугласа Крокфорда

Comment: @ruslik, Дуглас - уважаемый чувак, его мнение имеет вес. Плюс, на мой взгляд, конструкцию `}());` проще набирать, чем `})();`.

Comment: Первый вариант не работает со стралочными функциями

Answer (score 1):

Исправленный код

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
(function(i) {setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 100)}(i))
}
```

Не работает

```
((i)=>setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 100)(i))
```

Работает

```
((i)=>setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 100))(i)
```

Comment: Вы на русском stackoverflow, а значит, ответы можно и нужно писать на русском